# I have write some code for paid-member-subscriptions plugin but how I can overwrite class-shortcodes.php file

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Need to add custom code in paid-member-subscriptions/includes/class-shortcodes.php

I have tried to create the same folder in theme mytheme/paid-member-subscriptions/includes/class-shortcodes.php and added custom work in there

Comment: can you share your code in here ?

Comment: I'm getting custom URL that assigned in backend page

<?php
$get_redirection = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pms-content-restrict-custom-redirect-url', true )
?>
<p class="login-submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ); ?>" class="button button-primary" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_log_in'] ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $get_redirection; ?>" />
</p>

Comment: can you share i your question not in this comment so  other people can also solve the problem thanks

Comment: Did not get you where I need to share my question ?